# Reach a MySQL instance through multiple tunnels

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've a MySQL instance running on a server that I cannot reach directly but only through another server, so I have to reach it like:

`[local] --> [server1] --> [server2]`

Which command should I use to do this? I tried like everything but it seems to stop on the first one..

This is one of the command I've tried:

`ssh -N -p 22 -c 3des myUser@1.1.1.1 -L 3306/1.1.1.1/3310 -R 3310/2.2.2.2/3306`

1.1.1.1 -> server1

2.2.2.2 -> server2

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'd try changing the remote port on the local forward to a server that already exists on 1.1.1.1 to test it, and test the remote forward from the shell on 1.1.1.1 via nmap or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down

```
-N
```

I assume you don't want to execute a remote a command otherwise you could have done

```
ssh -t myUser@1.1.1.1 "ssh myUser@2.2.2.2"
```

Then `-p 22 -c 3des` Port and explicitly selecting a cipher

The local binding `-L 3306/1.1.1.1/3310` which translates to  `local-port:remote-host:remote-port`

Up until here, you are connecting as `myUser@1.1.1.1` and binding port 3306 on your machine to 3310 on 1.1.1.1.

`-R` does the exact opposite of `-L`. You bind a port remotely so when you connect to that remote host port you connect locally.

There's at least two way to do it. Either `ssh -f -N myUser@1.1.1.1 -L 3306:2.2.2.2:3310` and then `ssh myUser@localhost -p 3306`
or check [ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) and add something like this

```
Host 1.1.1.1
    HostName 1.1.1.1
    User myUser
    LocalForward 3306 127.0.0.1:3310
```

Comment: In the end a colleague made it work setting one more tunnel on the server1 pointing the server2, so something like you said. Thanks for the explanation btw, very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL is running on `server2`, you can try:

```
ssh -L 3306:2.2.2.2:3306 1.1.1.1
```

This will make a tunnel between your local 3306 port, and the `server2` port 3306.

You then connect to `localhost` in your MySQL client.